# Inserting SubItems to ListView On C#

Tags: c#, listview, textbox

Hello,
I have 3 Text Boxes and need their text to be inserted into a ListView by their matching columns when a button click event occurs. I tried this:

```
 ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
 lvi.SubItems.Add(textBox3.Text);
 lvi.SubItems.Add(textBox4.Text);
 lvi.SubItems.Add(textBox5.Text);
```

Although it doesn't seem to do it. Any suggestions?

Comment: *When* do you create this ListViewItem? Do you add it to a ListView?

Answer (score 0):

You'l have to create a [ListViewItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.aspx), and then you'l have to add it to your list. For example:

```
ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem();
item1.Content = textBox1.Text;
yourListName.Items.Add(item1); //Or SubItems
```

Good luck!